# Git rebase when we have feature branching

Tags: git, github, merge, bitbucket, rebase

I have a master branch from which I have created a development branch.
From development branch, I am further creating two feature branches Feature_1 and Feature_2.
Developers will work on the features and once the feature is completed it will be merged into the Development branch.

Now what if Feature_1 gets completed and is merged into the Development branch and once Feature_2 is completed, I will go for merging it to the Development branch but this feature branch is not updated and I suspect that it will lead to merge conflict.

How to avoid that merge conflict?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update feature_2 branch with the develop  branch  using git pull. If you have any conflicts you need to fix them.then you can push feature_2 changes in to develop branch, when it is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Your course of actions should be like this :

1. Before merging your feature_branch merge `development` to that branch. ex:- merge development to feature_2 use `git merge`.
2. Then Resolve any conflicts you have because you don't want conflicts to be part of your development branch.
3. After resolving conflict, merge your feature_2 branch to development branch.
4. If you are not making any direct commits to `master`, then merge development to master otherwise follow steps from 1-3 with merging master to development then development to master after resolving any conflicts if present.